# Application with envers fails on schema vaildation: REV column is of wrong type - found [int8 (Types#BIGINT)], but expecting [int4 (Types#INTEGER)]

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I have two Spring Boot applications working with the same database. The main app is uses the database fully, the other app is meant for reporting (basically read data created by the main app).

The main app uses envers (org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:5.3.1.Final), it creates audit tables to track changes (tables are created by liquibase). I need to read historical data by the reporting app, so I added envers to that app as well. Below are some snippets from the reporting app.

Entity example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "applications")
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = BaseEntity.class)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Getter
public class ApplicationEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private ClientEntity client;

    private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

Superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners({PreventModificationsListener.class})
@ToString(of = "id")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Getter
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @VisibleForTesting
    @Setter(PACKAGE)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;
}
```

Configuration:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: true
        defaultSchema: public
        order_updates: true
        jdbc:
          fetch_size: 0
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: validate
        show_sql: false
        format_sql: false
        enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
      org.hibernate:
        envers:
          audit_table_prefix: audit_
          audit_table_suffix:
```

As a result reporting app fails during starts on schema validation:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [rev] in table [audit_xyz]; found [int8 (Types#BIGINT)], but expecting [int4 (Types#INTEGER)]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateColumnType(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    ... 136 common frames omitted
```

Any help and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: If this is a test environment you could drop the related table and let hibernate create it from scratch by setting `hbm2ddl_auto` property to `update`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that both applications are using the same dialect class?

Comment: @dashboard The reporting app should leave the database intact, since it's initially was created for the main app. I can do that on test env, but we will have to go to prod after that. :)

Comment: @Naros I have already double-checked that it's `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect` under `hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar` for both applications.

Comment: @deniss-s It sounds like the database may have been created with the wrong data-type than what the Hibernate dialect would have used.  You can either disable validation by Hibernate or alter the table manually and make sure your liquibase scripts are updated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my colleagues have pointed out on difference between two applications that turned out the be the missing link.

Revision entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "audit_revisions")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_gen", sequenceName = "audit_revisions_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@RevisionEntity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Getter
public class AuditRevision {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_gen", strategy = SEQUENCE)
    @RevisionNumber
    private Long id;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    private Date revisionDate;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the link between this class and the problem decribed ?

Comment: Class `AuditRevision` was missing in one application.